# No cookies in my code but when uploaded to my domain chrome gives SameSite attribute error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cookies, samesite

When I upload my code to Infinity Free my CSS and images do not load on the website and I get an error code saying, " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" and another error saying, "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute".
I have linked screenshot of the error messages below and I have linked my websitehttp://laurieelizabeth.infinityfreeapp.com/WDGD150-FinaleAssignment-Java_Canvas/.

PLEASE HELP!
[image: error message]

[image: error]

[image: files]
[image: file layout in code]

Comment: check response headers in network tab, the server might be setting cookies in headers (for example session id cookie)

Comment: can't reproduce - only one cookie `__test` IS created - but it does not produce the "issue" shown in the question - perhaps clear your cookies and try again

Comment: If you clear cookies, open network tab in devtools, enable "preserve log", than you can find, that when you first open your website it loads html with javascript in it, which sets the `__test` cookie and loads `aes.js` file., than redirects to _your_  page with `?i=1`. This must be a tracker set by your hosting provider.